# Why isn't the output right?

Tags: arrays, c, structure

```
union test
{
int x;
char arr[4];
int y;
};

#include<stdio.h>
int main()
    {
    union test t;
    t.x = 0;
    t.arr[1] = 'G';
    printf("%s", t.arr);
    return 0;
    }
```

Predict the output of the above program. Assume that the size of an integer is 4 bytes and size of a character is 1 byte.

Why shouldn't the answer be Garbage character followed by 'G', followed by more garbage characters?

Comment: The correct answer is prints nothing

Comment: `t.x = 0` sets all 4 characters to 0. Do you know how unions work?

Comment: ("size of character is 1 byte" - C guarantees `sizeof(char)==1` _always_)

Comment: Exactly which garbage characters are you expecting?

Comment: I mean first character of array has been initialised as G and others should contain garbage value. @klutt

Comment: @HolyBlackCat With utmost humility, Can u justify your claim?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Can you send some supporting articles etc.?

Comment: @GirikGarg This is very basic knowledge. Any site explaining unions should be able to explain this.

Comment: @GirikGarg https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/

Comment: Note that arrays are indexed from 0, not 1.  The assignment `t.arr[1] = 'G';` is not initializing the first element of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 4 byte ints here:

```
t.x = 0;
```

write four 0 bytes into the union. That overwrites all the elements in arr[].

```
t.arr[1] = 'G';
```

writes a 'G' into the second byte of the union. There are still 3 zero-bytes: one before the G and two after the G.

```
printf("%s", t.arr);
```

prints up to the first 0 byte in t.arr, which is the first byte in t.arr because you wrote 4 zeroes into the union. No output.